# InputFilter Pattern isn't allowing decimal

Tags: android, regex, string-formatting, android-input-filter

I want a user to be able to input numbers such as the following.
Valid:
~0
~0.00
~12.34
~301.7
~4

Invalid
~01
~3.001

In short, it allows decimal numbers up to two decimal places.

This is what I've been trying to use

```
Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("|(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?");
```

When I try to type a "." in the field, it won't let me.

Comment: Did you supply the field type to allow numerical and decimal values?

Comment: @hwnd Do you mean using `android:inputType = "numberDecimal"`? It behaves the same way whether or not I declare that in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your validation pattern needs to match the input *as you are entering it*. In your case, as soon as you type in the ".", your entry is invalid. For example, if you are trying to enter `1.23`, when you are entering the decimal point your entry becomes `1.`, which *does not* match your regexp.

Try replacing `{1,2}` with `{0,1,2}` in your expression to allow a trailing ".".